# How to check whether memory leakage is happening in Hibernate's SessionFactory?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, memory-leaks, sessionfactory

I am new to Spring and Hibernate development environment. I have been working on a web application which is using Spring 2.5 and Hibernate 3.

Now I want to check whether there is any memory leakage is happening due to Hibernate's Session Factory.

Please help me to do this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check out my answer. You may up vote and accept if serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use profiling tools to analyze the Memory leakage. There are several commercial Java Profiling Tool, some of them which supports Spring and Hibernate are listed below:

- [Your Kit](https://www.yourkit.com/features/)
- [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)

There are some open-source Profiling tools specified in this article, not sure about the support for Hibernate and Spring:
[Effective Java Profiling With Open Source Tools](http://www.infoq.com/articles/java-profiling-with-open-source)

Comment: thanks for the answer but can you please tell me how to check exactly Hibernate SessionFactory is causing issues?